# How to make İnspector panel to standard view unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am a newbie at Unity. I did accidentally my inspector panel free. I want to restore the panel for the first time at Unity. How can I make it?

Here is the image the free panel:

[image]

I want to set it to right side again.

How can I fix it?

Comment: just move it and dock it, or reset the view

Comment: I closed the tap. And I click to ctrl + 3. It is still same point.

Comment: How can I do that? (reset the view)

Comment: its a menu optikon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the panel by dragging it towards the edge of another panel, and let go of the mouse when a blue outline shows up. This signals that you can place the panel there. In your case, drag the panel towards the right side of the Scene tab.